# What does a server-side language do?

Tags: server-side

This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I know it won't be my last. I am wonder what do server-side languages actualy do? Do they generate a html file based on whatever your code says?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Server side languages compile to generate an HTML page that is sent to the client (to the browser) over HTTP or HTTPS. For example, in ASP, each HTML page has a "Code Behind" attribute which represents server side language (such as C#), which, when running, alternates the HTML page and sends it rendered and finalized to the client. You can read much more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting).

Answer (score 0):

Server side languages are useful when you want to display a dynamic web pages where content changes with data saved in your database for example. One of the example is PHP.